# Join TableA, TableB and TableC to get data from TableA and TableC

Tags: sql-server-2008

Why I am getting so many records for this

```
SELECT e.OneColumn, fb.OtherColumn
FROM  dbo.TABLEA FB
INNER JOIN dbo.TABLEB eo ON Fb.Primary = eo.foregin
INNER JOIN dbo.TABLEC e ON eo.Primary =e.Foreign
WHERE FB.SomeOtherColumn = 0
```

When I am running this I am getting Millions of records which is not the correct case, all tables has less number of records.

I need to get the columns from TableA and TableC and because they are not joined logically so I have to use TableB to act as bridge

**EDIT**

Below is the count:

```
TABLEA = 273551
TABLEB = 384412
TABKEC = 13046
```

Above Query = After 2 minutes I have forcefully canceled the query.. till that time the count was **11437613**

Any suggestion?

Comment: The select looks correct. Do you expect a one to one relationship between TableA and TableC?

Comment: You have changed this to be nonspecific, so check your actual code to see if you have an aliasing problem in the joins. Sometimes this happens when you do something like  on Eo.Id = EO.ID by accident and end up with a cross join.

Comment: @HLGEM The above query is the replica of what I am using. I have just changed the column and table names

Comment: what is the output of the following:
count(Primary) from dbo.TABLEA,
count(foregin) from dbo.TABLEB, 
count(Primary) from dbo.TABLEB,
count(foregin) from dbo.TABLEC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out what is going on in such a query where the results are not as expected, I tend to do this. First I change to a SELECT * (Note this is only for figuring out the problem, do not use SELECT * on production, ever!) Then I add an order by for the ID frield from tableA if there is not one in the query.

So now I run the query up to the first table including any where conditions that are from the first table. I comment out the rest. I note the number of records returned.

Now I add in the second table and any where conditions from it. If I am expecting a one to relationship, and if this query doesn't return the smae number of records, then I look at the data that is being returned to see if I can figure out why. Since the contents are ordered by the table1 ID, you can ususally see examples of some records that are duplicated fairly easily and then scroll over until you find the field that causes the differnce. Often this means that you need some sort of addtional where clause or aggregation on the fields in the next table to limit to only one record. JUSt note down the problem at this point though as you may be able tomake the change more effectively in the next join.

So add inteh the third table and again, not the number of records and then look closely at the data where the id from A is repeated. LOok at the columns you intend to return, are they always teh same for an id?  If they are differnt then you do not havea one-one relationship and you need to understand that either theri is a data integrity problem or you are mistaken in thinking there is a one-to-one. If tehy are the same, then a derived table may be in order. You only need the ids from tableb so the join could look something like this:

```
JOIN (SELECT MIn(Primary), foreign FROM TABLEB GROUP BY foreign) EO ON Fb.Primary = eo.foreign
```

Hope this helps.